# Why is timeclose and timenow variable in my code works with the indicator function but not the strategy function?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm working with a bot in pinescript, here's my code:

```
//@version=5    
indicator("timeStrat")
secondsLeft = barstate.isrealtime ? (time_close - timenow) / 1000 : na
// Display countdown on the chart
plot(series=secondsLeft, title="Seconds left")
```

The code plot the time left in second in a 1 min chart. It works pretty well. I need this feature for my strategy, but when turn this code into a strategy like:

```
//@version=5
strategy("timeStrat")
secondsLeft = barstate.isrealtime ? (time_close - timenow) / 1000 : na
// Display countdown on the chart
plot(series=secondsLeft, title="Seconds left")
```

It doesn't work and it always plot a negative value, I really need help. Very grateful if anyone can help me to get over this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, strategies are calculated by bar close. You can force it recalculate on every real-time tick using `calc_on_every_tick = true` parameter and match the indicator results:

```
//@version=5
strategy("timeStrat", calc_on_every_tick = true)
secondsLeft = barstate.isrealtime ? (time_close - timenow) / 1000 : na
// Display countdown on the chart 
plot(series=secondsLeft, title="Seconds left")
```

> **calc_on_every_tick (const bool)** Specifies whether the strategy should
> be recalculated on each realtime tick. If **true**, when the strategy is
> running on a realtime bar, it will recalculate on each chart update.
> If **false**, the strategy only calculates when the realtime bar closes.
> The argument used does not affect strategy calculation on historical
> data. This setting can also be changed in the strategy's
> "Settings/Properties" tab. Optional. The default is **false**.

Comment: Thank you so much man! U saved my day, hav a gud day! XDDD